# Variable from variable

Tags: bash, variable

What am I doing wrong here?

```
A_B_NAME="something"
X=A
Y=B

RESULT=`echo \${X}_\${Y}_NAME`
echo ${RESULT}
```

and I'm always getting A_B_NAME as a result, but want "something"

Thanks!
Michael

Comment: `\${X}_\${Y}_NAME` is not the *variable* `A_B_NAME`, which is `$A_B_NAME`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `eval` here (standard):

```
eval "RESULT=\$${X}_${Y}_NAME"
```

Or the `bash`-specific:

```
varname=${X}_${Y}_NAME
RESULT=${!varname}
```

And then:

```
printf '%s\n' "$RESULT"
```

remember `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data, and parameter expansions must be quoted when in list contexts.

Comment: Thank you Stephane! It works! have a nice evening/day